# Remove unwanted padding on lower resolutions

Tags: html, css, sass

```css
:root {
    --primary-color: #10b929ff;
    --background-light-grey: #696969;
    --background-dark-grey: #2f2f2f;
}

body {
    background: var(--background-light-grey);
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
    background: var(--background-dark-grey);
    padding: 1em;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    //position: fixed;
    
}   


footer {
    background: #2f2f2f;
}

nav {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 66%;
    right: 0;
    top:0;
    background-color: var(--background-dark-grey);
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2em;

    ul.primary-nav {
        margin-top: 5em;
    }
    
    li {
        a{
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            padding: .5em;
            text-align: right;
            font-size: 30px;

            &:hover{
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        }
    }
}

.mobile-menu-exit{
    float: right;
    margin: .5em;
    cursor: pointer;
}



nav.menu-btn {
    display: block;
    
}

.website-logo {
    display: flex;
    place-content: space-between;
}

.mobile-menu{
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 2em;
    //max-width: 10%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px){
    nav{
        width: 44%;
        padding-right: 30px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .mobile-menu{
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 2em;
        max-width: 10%;
    }
    .website-logo {
        display: flex;
        place-content: space-between;
    
        img{
            width: 200px;
        }
    }

    .mobile-menu-exit{
        float: right;
        margin: .5em;
        cursor: pointer;
        max-width: 10%;
    }
}

a {
    color: white;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

section {
    padding: 10em 0em 5em 0em;
}

.hero {
    text-align: center;
    //padding-bottom: 160px;
}

.hero-image{
    background-image: url("https://am3pap006files.storage.live.com/y4pNuJohtpUdzBTZoc4fAQHlLNdeLvEQERim4Rs1KspeWQaKszREazNg4Ljnl7YTmkR6Sgsa4MUN4kB4aAf-vbbEuFnP9EPp2tAExe-dH_9o45qLndBetYu64mzC8r1Ynb8pOgWBAoqfzUL6lgg-Oue0OCqK6PPNliLbVrv6A3Yhuqalg__GtCNUkfzHJbwEuEtMWtpMjsvc_zHKMDeI1jNt5lG7eLxLiR5TluSAml-UuQ/IMG_0560.jpg?psid=1&width=720&height=486");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 160px;
}

.centre-col {

    color: white;

    h1 {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 3em;
        resize: horizontal;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    h3 {
        font-weight: 200;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .primary-cta {

        background: var(--primary-color);
        padding: .6em 1.3em;   
        text-decoration: none;
        border-radius: 5em;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }
}

.instagram-feed {
    padding-top: 00px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    z-index: 0;
}
.eapps-link img {
    display:none !important;
}

.club-vision-values {
    background: var(--background-light-grey);
    z-index: 1;
    top: 40%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-right: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.the-coaches{
    padding: 20px;

   ul{
    max-width: 500px;
    //padding-top: 10px;
    display: gird;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    }
}

.coach-list {
    column-count: 2;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
}

.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: var(--primary-color);
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 40px;

    h1 {
        margin: 4px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 8px;
        //padding-top: 3px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
    .coach-list {
        column-count: 2;
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: auto;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1080px){
    .coach-list {
        display: inline;
        max-width: 2600px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .the-coaches{
        padding: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
        margin: auto;
        ul {
            max-width: 2200px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            padding-left: 40px;
            padding-right: 40px;
        }
    }

    .card {
        margin: 10px;
    }
}

.footer{

    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.footer-container{
    
    max-width: 1670px;
    margin:auto;
}

.footer-col {
    color: white;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 0 35px;
}

.footer-col h4{
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.about-us {
    line-height: 25px;
}

.footer-col h4::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom: -10px;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    height: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50px;
}

.row
{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;   
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
}

.footer{
    padding: 60px;
}

.footer-col .social-links a{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    margin:0 10px 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.footer-col .social-links a:hover{
    color: #24262b;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

/*responsive*/

@media(max-width: 767px){
    .footer-col{
      width: 50%;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  }
  @media(max-width: 574px){
    .footer-col{
      width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>New Era Boxing</title>
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
     <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
     <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css">
 </head>
 <body>
     <div class="navbar">
         <div class="website-logo">
            <img id="logo" class="logo" src="Images/logo.svg" alt="The club logo">

            <img id="mobile-cta" class="mobile-menu" src="images/menu.svg" alt="Open Navigation">
            <nav>
                <img id="mobile-exit" class="mobile-menu-exit" src="images/exit.svg" alt="Exit Navigation">

                <ul class="primary-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Classes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
                
                
            </nav>
         </div>
     </div>
     
     <section class="hero-image">
        <div class="container">
                <!-- <img src="images/raul.JPG" alt="Raul"> -->
            <div class="centre-col">
                <h1>First-class boxing training<br>
                    for youths and adults alike</h1>
                <h3>We provide a supportive and inclusive training environment</h3>
                <div class="hero-cta">
                    <a href="#" class="primary-cta">View our timetable</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </section>

     <section class="instagram-feed">
        <script src="https://apps.elfsight.com/p/platform.js" defer></script>
        <div class="elfsight-app-a2b6cbed-0090-4fd3-9a99-b6ce405f0cbf"></div>     
     </section>

<section class="club-vision-values">
         <div>
             <h2>Our Club</h2>
             <p>New-Era Boxing Club was formed in 2011 by Mark Bebbington and focuses on teaching core values as well as providing first class training for youths and adults alike</p>
         </div>
         <div>
            <h2>Our Vision</h2>
            <p>Our vision is to create opportunities for members through boxing, education and personal development in doing so we will provide a supportive and inclusive training environment.</p>
         </div>
         <div>
            <h2>Our Values</h2>
            <p>New Era Boxing emphasises the core value of Equality, Integrity, Compassion, Resilience and Humility at the heart of the clubs activities.</p>
         </div>
     </section>

     <section class="the-coaches">
            <div class="coach-list">
                <ul class="left">
                    <li>
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="images/mark.PNG" alt="Mark Bebbington - Lead Coach" style="width:100%">
                            <h1>Mark Bebbington</h1>
                            <p>Lead Coach</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="images/mark.PNG" alt="Mark Bebbington - Lead Coach" style="width:100%">
                            <h1>Mark Bebbington</h1>
                            <p>Lead Coach</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="images/mark.PNG" alt="Mark Bebbington - Lead Coach" style="width:100%">
                            <h1>Mark Bebbington</h1>
                            <p>Lead Coach</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="images/mark.PNG" alt="Mark Bebbington - Lead Coach" style="width:100%">
                            <h1>Mark Bebbington</h1>
                            <p>Lead Coach</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
            </div>
        </div>
     </section>

     <footer class="footer">
         <div class="footer-container">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="footer-col">
                     <h4>Phone Us</h4>
                         <ul>
                             <li>07830 085132</li>
                         </ul>
                 </div>
                 <div class="footer-col">
                     <h4>Email Us</h4>
                         <ul>
                             <li class="email">neweraboxing@hotmail.co.uk</li>
                         </ul>
                 </div>
                 <div class="footer-col">
                    <h4>About Us</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="about-us"><a href="#">
                            FAQs
                            </a></li>
                            <li class="about-us"><a href="#">
                            Club Partners
                            </a></li>
                            <li class="about-us"><a href="#">
                            Timetable
                            </a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
                 <div class="footer-col">
                     <h4>Follow Us</h4>
                         <div class="social-links">
                             <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></i></a>
                             <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></i></a>
                             <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></i></a>
                             <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></i></a>
                         </div>
                 </div>

             </div>
         </div>

     </footer>

    <script>
     const mobileBtn = document.getElementById('mobile-cta')
              nav = document.querySelector('nav')
              mobileBtnExit = document.getElementById('mobile-exit');

        mobileBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            nav.classList.add('menu-btn');
        })

        mobileBtnExit.addEventListener('click', () => {
            nav.classList.remove('menu-btn');
        })
    </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

I am viewing my website in the Developer tools but whenever I try to view it in a mobile resolution below 400px wide it seems to add this unwanted padding to the right side. Sometimes this disappears, but other times it just stays there. Is this a common issue and are there any suggestions on how to fix this please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhd1e.png)

Comment: it's impossible to say without looking at the actual code. 
My guess is that you have an element that creates an overflow, so try to hide all your elements one by one, until you find the guilt.

Comment: could you share the CSS structure and HTML so that we can help you what might be the issue here?

Comment: I have added code snippets, apologies I should have included them originally.

Comment: Please could you reduce your code to the bit that is incorrect - see [mcve]

Comment: right now the overflow is always visible and it is due to the alt text "open navigation" in the header. Without the issue no longer happens

Comment: Thanks Fabrizio, how did you resolve the issue? I've tried removing the alt text, also tried to set the overflow on the header to hidden but still getting the same issue.